# Hybrid map type does not load in google maps api

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add google map onto my Angular application and have troubles with hybrid map type. I'm using [js-api-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) to dynamically load the Google Maps API, which seems to work fine. In component I'm creating the map instance with some options as following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.mapOptions = {
   mapId: <imagine-proper-map-id-here>,
   scrollwheel: true,
   disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
   streetViewControl: false,
   clickableIcons: false,
   fullscreenControl: false,
   zoomControl: true,
   zoom: 4,
   maxZoom: 19,
   minZoom: 2,
   mapTypeControl: true,
   keyboardShortcuts: true,
   draggable: true,
   tilt: 0,
   rotateControl: false
 };
 this.googleMapService.loadScript().then(async (googleInstance) => {
  const { Map, InfoWindow } = (await googleInstance.maps.importLibrary('maps')) as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
  this.map = new Map(this.document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement, this.mapOptions);
  this.infoWindow = new InfoWindow();
});
```

So when I'm using '[DEMO_MAP_ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/start)' as this.mapOptions.mapId everything works fine and all map types load as they should. But when I'm trying to switch to proper mapId I created in Maps Management only map types that work are: roadmap, terrain and satellite. Instead of hybrid map only grey background loads and there is an error thrown by google api in developer console.

[image: Does not look like hybrid map]

[image: Error in console]

I tried to create new mapId and use it instead but it did not work as well.
Does anybody have any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the map ID you were using? Or just the setting you put should be fine.

Comment: And please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can help you better. Providing us the packages you used and etc should be good.